# submit & array php

Tags: php, arrays, addition

I have one question. So, I have built my PHP application with two text fields (First Name, Last Name) and one submit button (like "Add Contact"). I don't use MySQL. I use array. I want following:
The first time when i click submit button I should see the first name and last name of my contact. Second time when i click submit button I should again see the first conact and the new one. Example:

First Click -  I see: John Johnson

Second Click - I see: John Johnson (old contact),  Peter Peterson (new contact)

Hers is my code:

```
   <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

class Contact {

    private $lastname;
    private $firstname;

    public function getLastname() {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname($lastname) {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    public function getFirstname() {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname($firstname) {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }

}

?>



   <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
class Controller {

    private $arr;

    public static function addContact($person) {
        $this->arr[] = $person;
    }

    public function getArr() {
        return $this->arr;
    }

    public function setArr($arr) {
        $this->arr = $arr;
    }

}
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" name="form" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fname" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lname" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Person"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <?php
        include_once 'Contact.php';
        include_once 'Controller.php';

        $controller = new Controller();



        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $person = new Contact();
            $person->setFirstname($_POST['fname']);
            $person->setLastname($_POST['lname']);
            $controller->addContact($person);

            print_r($controller->getArr());
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, please?

Comment: Options are, you can use a session or cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier you can use sessions as a storage, but it only lasts until session timeouts (defaults to 30 minutes).

```
<?php
session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['names']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
    $_SESSION['names'] = array();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $_SESSION['names'][] = $_POST['name'];
} 
?>

<?php foreach($_SESSION['names'] as $name): ?>
  <?php echo $name ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, your last sentence is correct: "...As mentioned earlier you can use sessions as a storage, but it only lasts until session timeouts (defaults to 30 minutes)". I know that. I'm actually a JAVA programmaer and there is something like <useBean clas="..." scope="session" id="..." />. Thanks

Comment: When i click the submit button the array don't have to "refresh" . Can i solve this proble with instances of array or class. And here in your code: if (!empty($_POST)) can i change it with this: if(isset($_POST['submit'])) ???

Comment: To see what name submit button has in $_POST, print it out with print_r($_POST); And then you can use isset instead. What do you mean by array refresh?

Comment: When i click to reload page. Maybe if you are JAVA programmer you can understand. There is useBean.

Comment: See my edit, maybe this is what you meant. Really try to describe your situation better. The more words you use, the more likely we are to understand you.

Comment: Do you know JSP? Your code is what i want. But there is an error ocurred. Never mind. I try to the same thing without session.

Comment: Your code works. You are awesome :D . Do you know JAVA? Do you know how to implement my problem without sessions?

Comment: If my answer is the solution, please mark it as answered :) And yes, use database or cookies (set a cookie and delete on second request). But now that you have the basic skeleton you can google around and figure it out.

Comment: Yes, i will mark your answer as positive. But is there in PHP something like <useBean scope="sesion" id="..." class="className" /> in JAVA? This will be also an solution for my problem. I need this, you know, in database we have one to many relation, and so I have, for example, 10 contacts that belong to one user as in my example. So the user will add to contact all ten user and than in database. I think it is much more efficient.

Comment: You can put anything in session - $_SESSION['name'] = new Contact;

Answer (score 2):

You need to start a session and add the array to the $_SESSION array:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/sessions.shtml

But be warned that the data will only exist as long as the current session exists.

Comment: Yes, your last sentence is correct: "...data will only exist as long as the current session exists. I know that. I'm actually a JAVA programmaer and there is something like <useBean clas="..." scope="session" id="..." />. Can you write the code here. Thanks